# Message: Undefine variable: exam

Tags: codeigniter

controller: Test.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Test extends CI_Controller 
{
    function __construct() 
    {
        parent :: __construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->model('Fetch_data');
    }
    public function agriculture_exam()
    {
        $stream = 'agriculture';
        $data['exam'] = $this->Fetch_data->top_agriculture_exams($stream);
        $this->load->view('header',$data);
    }
}
```

view: header.php

```
<ul class="list">
<?php 
    foreach($exam as $row) 
    {
       echo "<li><a href='#'>".$row['exam_name']."</a></li>"; 
    }
?>
</ul>
```

model: Fetch_data.php

```
<?php  
    class Fetch_data extends CI_Model  
    {  
        function __construct()  
        {   
            parent::__construct();  
        }  
        public function top_agriculture_exams($stream)
        {
            $this->db->select('exam_name');
            $this->db->from('all_exams_details');
            $this->db->where('field',$stream);
            $this->db->order_by('exam_name');
            $this->db->limit('10');
            $query = $this->db->get(); 
            $result = $query->result_array();
            return $result;
        }
    }
```

I am new in ci. In controller i.e. Test.php I am defining $stream='agriculture' and pass $stream variable to top_agriculture_exams model. Now, when I am fetching data on header.php file it show me a Message: Undefine variable: $exam I don't know why. So, how can I fix it ?please help me.

Thank You

Comment: `print_r($data['exam']); exit;` in your controller and check the result

Comment: Its done @YadhuBabu its working.

Comment: any one help me plss

Comment: in your query change `$this->db->select('exam_name');` to `$this->db->select('*');` and check

Comment: print the result in another view page something like `test.php` just to check. Nothing seems to be wrong with your code

Comment: `Message: Undefine variable: exam` can you paste the complete error with line number in it?

Answer (score 0):

Please check my below code. This will help you.

```
<ul class="list">
    <?php
    if ($exam !== NULL):
        foreach ($exam as $row):
            echo "<li><a href='#'>" . $row['exam_name'] . "</a></li>";
        endforeach;
    endif;
    ?>
</ul>
```

Also cna you please put this code in View and share result.

```
<?php
var_dump($exam);
?>
```

Also check your model code below.

```
<?php  
    class Fetch_data extends CI_Model  
    {  
        function __construct()  
        {   
            parent::__construct();  
        }  
        public function top_agriculture_exams($stream)
        {
            $this->db->select('exam_name');
            $this->db->from('all_exams_details');
            $this->db->where('exam_name',$stream);
            $this->db->order_by('exam_name');
            $this->db->limit('10');
            $query = $this->db->get(); 
            $result = $query->result_array();
            return $result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: also in your query `$this->db->where('field',$stream);` What will be the `field` here.?

Comment: field is a column in all_exams_details table

Comment: Can you please share your table here..?  `show create table all_exams_details;`, Fire this query in server and share the output

Answer (score 0):

instead of accessing it using the element array try accessing it using object.

change below code in your Fetch_data.php file.

```
//$result = $query->result_array();
$result = $query->result();
```

and access it by object in your header.php. here's an example below.

```
<ul class="list">
 <?php foreach($exam as $row): ?> 
      <?=  "<li><a href='#'>" . $row->exam_name . "</a></li>" ?>
 <?php endforeach;
</ul>
```

where exam_name is equal to the column in your database.